# unexpected results when checking if two arrays are equals in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of numbers to be checked for sort");
    int amount = input.nextInt();

    int[] list = new int[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        list[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    // Print the original array
    printArray(list);

    // list2 will contain the sorted list of elements
    int[] list2 = sortArray(list);
    printArray(list2);

    // Print the results
    if (Arrays.equals(list, list2)) {
        System.out.println("Already sorted!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not sorted");
    }
}

// Print array method
public static void printArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}


// function to sort the array
public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) {
    boolean changed = true;
    do {
        changed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                // swap array[i] with array[i + 1]
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = temp;
                changed = true;
            }
        }
    } while (changed);

    return array;
  }
 }
```

**Original Question:** *Write a test program that prompts the user to enter a list and displays whether the list is sorted or not. Here is a sample run. Note that the first number in the input indicates the number of the elements in the list.*

**My Question:** *Why am I getting **"Already sorted!"** even when I enter an unsorted list?*

**Output when I run the program:**

```
gurbhej@Nanda:~/Dropbox/Programming/Java Programs/Test$ java Test 
Enter the amount of numbers to be checked for sort
5
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 3

Unsorted
4
3
5
6
3
Sorted
3
3
4
5
6
Already sorted!
gurbhej@Nanda:~/Dropbox/Programming/Java Programs/Test$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `sortArray` method sorts the array *in place*, and returns a reference to the same object. Therefore you don't even have two arrays to compare - you're comparing one array with itself.

To see this more clearly, change your code to this:

```
// list2 will contain the sorted list of elements
int[] list2 = sortArray(list);
printArray(list);
printArray(list2);
```

You'll now see the same array printed twice.

You need to clone the array before sorting it, basically. I would personally clone it, pass the reference to the clone into the method, but *not* have a return value - that makes it clearer that it's modifying the existing array:

```
int[] list2 = (int[]) list.clone();
sortArray(list2);
```

Comment: How many times am I going to make the same mistake? have to pay attention :)

Comment: @JavaNoob If this is your answer, please select the green checkmark to indicate this is your *Accepted Answer*

Comment: @BLaZuRE he cant yet, it needs to be up longer before an answer can be accepted

Comment: @BLaZuRE: 7 more minutes before I am allowed to accept the answer!

Comment: @darijan Did you mean list.clone() and not list2.clone();

Answer (score 1):

Both the reference - `list` and `list2` are pointing to the same array. That is why they will return true, if you test Array equality on them.